# Flutter 2 issue: XCode cannot access compile-time variables ($DART_DEFINES)

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to migrate a Flutter project from Flutter v1.22.4 to Flutter v2.0.6.

In the `flutter run` command, we define some dart-define variables like `--dart-define=DEFINEEXAMPLE_APP_NAME=My_App_Staging --dart-define=DEFINEEXAMPLE_APP_SUFFIX=staging`.

Then, we use a pre-build action like the one defined in the article below, to use the dart-define variables as environment variables:

https://itnext.io/flutter-1-17-no-more-flavors-no-more-ios-schemas-command-argument-that-solves-everything-8b145ed4285d

```sh
function urldecode() { : "${*//+/ }"; echo "${_//%/\\x}"; }

IFS=',' read -r -a define_items <<< "$DART_DEFINES"


for index in "${!define_items[@]}"
do
    define_items[$index]=$(urldecode "${define_items[$index]}");
done

printf "%s\n" "${define_items[@]}"|grep '^DEFINEEXAMPLE_' > ${SRCROOT}/Flutter/flutter.xcconfig
```

The script worked perfectly in Flutter v1.22.4, but it's broken in Flutter v2.0.6. More specifically, nothing is printed when I add `echo "$DART_DEFINES"` to the beginning of the script, which suggests to me that `$DART_DEFINES` is null when passed to the pre-action. As a result of this, my build is failing.

One thing to note is that DART_DEFINES is defined correctly inside these two files auto-generated by Flutter during the build:

- ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig
- ios/Flutter/flutter_export_environment.sh

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Did you fix that somehow?

Comment: @HermannKlecker No, we ended up having to stop using DART_DEFINE

Comment: I found the issue in the meantime and made it working for android and iOS. There are two aspects here. First, between flutter 1.20 and 2.x there were changes to how flutter encodes the DART_DEFINE. It is Base64 encoded since flutter 2.0. 
Well, that does not explain that you don't see the environment variable at all. That may be fixed by selecting the correct source for the settings. I'll provede an answer. It may not help you anymore but might help others.

Comment: > It may not help you anymore but might help others.
Absolutely! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and soved it like this.

1. Most likely you did not provide anything as "Profice build settings from". The default is "None", unfortunately. You have to give your target, which is "Runner" per default. [[image: Edit the Schema][[image: Choose Runner]]
2. The other thing I noticed will not solve the issue that you described but must be fixed too. With version 2.x the value of DART_DEFINES is Base64 encoded. Instead of your function urldecode use somthing like:

   function entry_decode() { echo "${*}" | base64 --decode; }